# redux dispatch action and reducer with new state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have actions like:

```
export function login(){
  my_login(function(response){
    if(response.status == "ok"){
        loginSuccess(response)
        }
       })
      }

export function loginSuccess(response){
  return dispatch => {
  dispatch({ response, type: types.LOGIN });
  console.log("dispatched");
  console.log(getState()); ---> I want the updated state
  router.transitionTo("/some_url");----> after this I want to route it to somewhere
  };
}
```

When my `login` action is called it again calls `my_login` and then I am dispatching my `loginSuccess` action.

I have a reducer like:

```
const initialState = [
  {
    fname: null,
    lname: false,
  }
]

export default function login(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN:
    console.log("actions dude")
      console.log(action)
        return 
        [{
          fname: action.fname,
          lname: actin.lname,
        }]
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Here my state is not changing and I am not getting the `getState()` value in action above.

I dont think my reducer is called and state is updated.

Can anyone sugges me whats wrong in here ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing `dispatch(loginSuccess(response))`

Answer (score 2):

Beware of the bare return statement. One of the known pitfalls of automatic semicolon insertion is that `return` becomes `return;`.

So instead of:

```
return 
[{
  fname: action.fname,
  lname: action.lname,
}]
```

Do this instead:

```
return [{
  fname: action.fname,
  lname: action.lname,
}];
```